# Nested select inside insert with trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this statement

```
INSERT INTO brand(brand_id, NAME, cat_id)
SELECT NULL, name, cat_id
FROM category
WHERE type = $value
```

But I need to redo it so if `name` is already in table I will select also `brand_id` from table `brand`. How can i do that? Probably some trigger?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a select case

```
 INSERT INTO brand(brand_id, NAME, cat_id)
 SELECT 
         case brand_id when is null then NULL else brand_id end
       , name
       , cat_id
 FROM category
 WHERE type = $value
```

Comment: But I first need to get `name` from brand table then check if its same as name that i want to insert and if yes, then brand_id should be same as brand_id that is next to that name... When i tried to write it, it looks a bit difficult, because I need to get all the names from brand table, then iterate them and if any of them match then get the id from row and put it as brand_id, is that correct ? Can i do it with one statement ?

Comment: You comment is not clear to me  ... i suggest you of  update your question and show a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..

Comment: @rtom , Please check below query
`INSERT INTO brand(brand_id, NAME, cat_id)
 SELECT 
         case brand_id when is null then NULL else if( category.name = ( select name from brand where brand_id = category.brand_id )) then brand_id else 'your else condition' end
       , name
       , cat_id
 FROM category
 WHERE type = $value`

Comment: @rtom,  let me know if it helps or not